# How To Find The Best Control Point For Quadratic Bezier Curve?

Tags: bezier

I want to draw an airfoil with knowing it's coordinates.i decide to use quadratic bezier curve so with first and end points of bezier equation, how to find the best control point for this quadratic bezier curve that pass through a set of points? (coordinates of airfoils)

Answer (score 1):

The question you're asking is very similar to this one: [How can I fit a Bézier curve to a set of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6299019/507078)