# Creating cubic and/or quadratic Bezier curves to fit a path

Tags: algorithm, lua, interpolation, curve-fitting, bezier

I am working on a 2D game in Lua.
I have a path which is made up of a number of points, for example, points A to L: [image: points A to L]

I want to move an object smoothly along this path. To accomplish this, I wanted to create quadratic or cubic Bezier curves based on the points, and interpolate these curves. However, how do I fit the curves properly, such that the path isn't broken if eg. a curve stops and another starts in point F?

Comment: I think most solutions would assume a smooth curve at all points and not try to detect a break as in your point F. You might need to do that out-of-band, but that presents its own problem - what criteria do you use to determine a break?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know, and I think that's the root of the problem. Essentially the path needs corners like point F curved. Do I need to find some rotation value to indicate this maybe?

Comment: No you don't. You want to make a smooth curve through the points, and you might want to ultimately render that using Beziers, but the last thing you want here is *actual* Bezier curves, which don't go through points. You want Catmull-Rom curves, which are related to Bezier curves but *do* go through specified points. In addition, can you (in your post) describe what "smoothly" means? If you're thinking fixed speed, for instance, Bezier curves make that quite hard. Lastly: can you also show the path you think should connect these points? Because that determines suitable curve fitting.

Comment: see [Interpolation polynomial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214)
and [Proper implementation of cubic spline interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20517874/2521214) ... use interpolation it goes through the points ... and if needed bezier then convert the control points to Bezier ones no fitting needed equations are in the links

Answer (score 1):

Curve fitting is explained in this question: [How can I fit a Bézier curve to a set of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299019/how-can-i-fit-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve-to-a-set-of-data)

However, there is a must easier method to interpolate the points. It goes this way:

1. *Refine*: Place a point in the middle of each edge.
2. *Dual*: Place a point in the middle of each edge and remove the old points.
3. Repeat the *Dual* step several times.
4. Repeat from step one until the curve is smooth enough.

You can easily see that it works on paper. The resulting curve begins to approximate a series of bezier splines.

It is described more formally in this PDF file (Section 3): http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~jarek/courses/handouts/curves.pdf

Here is some Javascript code to do it:

```
function bspline_smooth(points, order) {

    // insert a point in the middle of each edge.
    function _refine(points) {
      var i, index, len, point, refined;
      points = [points[0]].concat(points).concat(points[points.length-1]);
      refined = [];
      index = 0;
      for (i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        point = points[i];
        refined[index * 2] = point;
        if (points[index + 1]) {
          refined[index * 2 + 1] = _mid(point, points[index + 1]);
        }
        index += 1;
      }
      return refined;
    }

    // insert point in the middle of each edge and remove the old points.
    function _dual(points) {
      var dualed, i, index, len, point;
      dualed = [];
      index = 0;
      for (i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        point = points[i];
        if (points[index + 1]) {
          dualed[index] = _mid(point, points[index + 1]);
        }
        index += 1;
      }
      return dualed;
    }

    function _mid(a, b) {
      return new Point(
        a.x + ((b.x - a.x) / 2),
        a.y + ((b.y - a.y) / 2) );
    }

    if (!order) {
       return points;
    }
    return bspline_smooth(_dual(_dual(_refine(points))), order - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to know math to do this.

Connect each point with the next point with a separate Bezier curve.

Bezier curves have "handles" attached to their end points. These handles are tangent to the curve (at the end points). To make a "smooth" path all you need to do is make the handles of every two adjacent Bezier curves "sit" on one line.

To understand this, experiment with a drawing program like GIMP (but probably almost any other software will do). Such programs even have a special key to make the "handles" of adjacent curves sit on a straight line (and be of the same length).

The only "hard" mathematical decision you'll have to make is to determine the lengths of these handles. Experiment. You might want to make it dependent on how far each 3 consecutive points deviate from being on a straight line, or on the distance between the points.

Lastly, as for moving a point (your "object") along the curve at a seemingly constant speed: You can use an adaptation of a method [like this one](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing).

Comment: The question says "curves" plural and specifically mentions quadratic and cubic forms, which implies the OP knows all of this already. It doesn't really answer the question, all of the important details are missing.

Comment: @Mark: I don't see what in my answer disagrees with his question. If he want "corners" in his overall path, then I already answered that: "smooth" is only when the handles are on the same line. I also mentioned a tip about "dependent on how far each 3 consecutive points deviate from being on a straight line" (e.g., points E F G in our case, so he can make the handles at F zero length). See my "To understand this" paragraph. Please don't make this seem complicated.

Comment: I say again, "all the important details are missing". This answer is wholly insufficient for helping someone with the task at hand, especially if they already know everything you said.