# Smoothing a hand-drawn free shape

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I am creating an app that allows the user to do some hand-drawing. The problem is I draw lines between the points where the user moved his finger so the resulting shape is somewhat jagged.

My question is how can I smooth the drawing? What is the best algorithm for dealing with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use some kind of [curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) (maybe [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)) to do it for you.

There is also this very nice [example](http://www.carlosicaza.com/?p=56) of how it could work. I could not find source code for it but i think that creator of this one has used algorithm from [Graphics Gems 1](http://iut-arles.univ-provence.fr/web/romain-raffin/sites/romain-raffin/IMG/pdf/PSchndeider_An_Algorithm_for_automatically_fitting_digitized_curves.pdf). You could find c code for it [here](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~graphics/books/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c) and i have found on SO also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525665/smoothing-a-hand-drawn-curve).