# UIBezierPath not drawing a smooth curve

Tags: ios, ios5, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am using UIBezierPath for drawing, and I have written the code on touch events and its working fine, but my curves are not smooth, when I am move my finger around and draw some curve, they are not smooth.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
    [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
}

#pragma mark - Touch Methods
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineWidth=5;
    myPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    myPath.flatness = 0.0;   

    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [pathArray addObject:myPath];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];    
}
```

Here is the image

[image]

In the above image if you see the letters a and d you will see that the curve is not smooth. What should I do, to get a smooth curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this line. it will solve your problem `myPath.miterLimit=-10;`.

Change the value if you need to any thing it takes float value

Comment: hey hi aalok, nice to see you again, hey your trick is not working, spikes are no more but the curve is not smooth, I am using your code which you had given link yesterday

Comment: so how to go about this, I am struggling from morning .:(

Comment: yes have to optimise it for smooth corves. Let's try and find out some  way to do it. need some research for that. and this needs time

Comment: i found that the change in linecapstyle is doing some work around but not very good smooth ness but some smoothness is achieved using `kCGLineJoinRound` try this out

Comment: hey aalok you cannot use this for linecapstyle, its hould be used for lineJoinStyle

Comment: ok, anyways, hey you get to know any clues regarding the same please let me know

Comment: This answer should not be accepted, the other answer points to the real reason. You’re not going to get smooth curves if you’re simply adding line segments.

Answer (score 4):

Well you are using `addLinePoint` so obviously you get lines, not curves. You would be interested in other methods to give you smooth curves: [addCurveToPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:) or [addQuadCurveToPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:). But as you can see from the API, besides the points you are actually drawing with your finger, you need also control points which do not come free with the drawing. Even Photoshop is asking you to move them around when doing curvature. In other words, making your hand drawing smooth "automagically" involves quite some mathematics. Google "smoothing hand drawn" and you will get at least these points to start with

[Smoothing a hand-drawn free shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363568/smoothing-a-hand-drawn-free-shape)

[Smoothing a hand-drawn curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525665/smoothing-a-hand-drawn-curve)

It is really not iOS specific at all.