# How to draw a smooth UIBezierPath for signatures?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

Currently I have implemented a `SignatureViewController` using a `PanGestureRecognizer`, a BezierPath and the methods `moveToPoint:` and `addLineToPoint:`, as it can be found a thousand times on the web. But the curves are not drawn smooth, which is a problem for signatures.

Can anybody give me an ObjC example showing how to calculate the control points for the method

```
- (void)addCurveToPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint controlPoint1:(CGPoint)controlPoint1 controlPoint2:(CGPoint)controlPoint2;
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829778/drawing-performance-over-time-for-a-uibezierpath-with-swift-for-ios) will be helpful. However, you have to do some optimizations

Answer (score 2):

`UIBezierPath` having a property `miterLimit` by using this we can smooth curve.

Go through the flollowing link this is similar to your requirement.
[UIBezierPath not drawing a smooth curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896557/uibezierpath-not-drawing-a-smooth-curve)

Hope it help's you.