# Calculating optimal count of splines from set of points

Tags: math, 2d, spline

This task is similar to tools like FreePen in Photoshop and etc.

A set of points (we get them from mouse input) needed to be interpolated into optimal count of splines.

I just don't know where to look.

Comment: Google 'spline interpolation' ?

Comment: Don't think that ordinary spline interpolation is solution.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you Google 'ordinary spline interpolation'.  You seem clueless, I offered a clue, if it's not a good clue, ho hum, that's the nature of SO.

Comment: Please. If you don't know - do not suggest.

Comment: Here is answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525665/smoothing-a-hand-drawn-curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you need to reduce number of points at first.
There is [Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to simplify polylines. C++ [implementation](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0205/algorithm_0205.htm)